# Background image not showing on animated div until browser window resized

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, visibility, window-resize

I got a strange issue - I have a `div` that I hide with CSS:

```
 .thediv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 87%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(pics/FrameWithBG1280.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 95% 87%;
  -webkit-background-size: 95% 87%;
  -moz-background-size: 95% 87%;
  -o-background-size: 95% 87%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 84%;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  top: -110%;
}
```

And show it via button click:

```
$('.thebutton').click(function(){ 
   $('.thediv').animate({top:'11%'})
});
```

Which works fine, except the `div` doesn't have its usual background picture until I resize browser window. When I resize browser window the background image appears. Tested in Chrome, Mozilla, Opera and Edge - all the same.

Any ideas why it could be happening?

Comment: It would be nice to mention which browser you're using.

Comment: Also please share all code (including CSS) that reproduces the error

Comment: Are you waiting for everything to load?

Comment: It would be better to use `.hide()` for this.

Comment: Tested in chrome, mozila, opera and edge. I added all relevant code in the question.  Yes, I am waiting for everything to load. Regarding .hide() - nto sure where Iwould use it in this case. And thanks for all your replies

Answer (score 1):

> The relative must be based on the absolute.

In your code, all values are relative (percentage). When "resize", the script adds the value in absolute units (px. Check it in DevTools) to this block and/or its ancestor, and therefore the percentages start to work and affect the image!

Solution: add values in absolute units to the block and/or its ancestors. You can also use *vh* and *vw* to determine the dependency on the size of the browser viewport.

> You cannot get a part of nothing, uncertainty or infinity.